Why is the set of ill-founded trees analytic?
tested on this subject tomorrow, would love for your help.
A tree T in a set theory sense is a set where for any t in T, if s is a subset of t then s is also in T.
It's ill-founded if it has an infinite branch, meaning there is a increasing sequence of set (by inclusion) in T.
Would post a pic but not enough karma yet so here's a screenshot:

Definition. Fix an enumeration $\{s_n\}_{n<\omega}$ of $\omega^{<\omega}$. For every $x\in 2^\omega$, let
$$R^x = \{s_n\in\omega^{<\omega}\mid x(n)\neq 0\}.$$
Define $\mathrm{Tr}\subseteq 2^\omega$ by
$$\mathrm{Tr} = \{x\in 2^\omega\mid R^x\text{ is a tree}\}.$$


Question.
Define $\mathrm{IF\subseteq Tr}$ by
$$\mathrm{IF} = \{x\in\mathrm{Tr}\mid R^x\text{ is ill-founded}\}.$$
Prove that $\mathrm{IF}$ is analytic.

Would love for your help since I didn't really understand how to reach this solution.

Your definition of tree seems incorrect. You probably want a set of sequences, and $s$ must be an initial subsequence of $t$. Anyway, you probably want to write down the definitions and question in the body of the text, rather than referring to an image elsewhere.

Hi Andres, how can I write my post in an aesthetically pleasing way? When I try to write math symbols it gets a little lost. Is there a site I can write it down in and paste here?

Let us simply write down the definition of being ill-founded: A tree $T\subseteq \omega^{<\omega}$ is ill-founded if it has an infinite branch. Put differently, $T$ is ill-founded if there is $B\in \omega^\omega$ such that for every $n<\omega$, $B\restriction n\in T$. It means that
$$\mathrm{IF} = \textstyle\bigcup_{B\in \omega^\omega} \bigcap_{n<\omega}\{x\in \mathrm{Tr}\mid B\restriction n\in R^x\}.$$
You can see that $\mathrm{Tr}$ is a closed set, and the set $\{x\in \omega^\omega\mid B\restriction n \in R^x\}$ is a clopen set, so $\mathrm{IF}$ is analytic.
